# Excel 2003 Relative Column References

Tags: excel

I have a worksheet, in which I want to reference data from another worksheet.

```
='Value List'!Z$1
```

is the formula I use to receive the data. Normally, I could drag the field down and it would change the column, but not the number (because of the $).

How it should look like:

```
='Value List'!Z$1
='Value List'!AA$1
='Value List'!AB$1
```

How it looks like:

```
='Value List'!Z$1
='Value List'!Z$1
='Value List'!Z$1
```

Why does it not work?

Comment: When you drag and drop down it will increase rows only not column. Thats   why your formula not working. Use offset function to to retrieve data from next column when drag down.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it may help you. Assuming you putting formula in A1 cell in another sheet.

```
=OFFSET('Value List'!$Z$1,0,ROW()-ROW($A$1))
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification to harun24hr's answer uses `INDEX` instead of `OFFSET`, because `OFFSET` [is a volatile function](http://blog.xlcubed.com/2011/08/warning-excel-can-get-volatile/) and that can slow down recalculation of your sheet:

```
=INDEX('Value List'!$Z$1:$Z$65535,ROW()-ROW($A$1)+1)
```

Here `$A$1` is the address of the first cell in the destination list (note `+1` compared to the `OFFSET` solution). Of course you could just substitute the actual number of the row here, but keeping the `ROW` function means it's less likely the function will break if the destination cells are moved or rows or columns are inserted.

`65535` is the highest row number you can have in Excel 2003; change this to something more appropriate if you wish.